# Assign value based on even/odd rows in R

Tags: r, indexing, rows, assign

I have a *dataframe* with 67000 rows, and I would like to replace the content of the odd rows with `Al` and the even rows with `Bt`. It should be quite straightforward but I am missing something.

```
 dataframe$variable <- "NA"`

 odd_indexes<-seq(1,nrow(dataframe),2)

 even_indexes<-seq(2,nrow(dataframe),2)
```

The following code doesn't work.

```
 dataframe$variable[odd_indexes,] <- "Al"

 dataframe$variable[even_indexes,] <- "Bt"
```

I get this error: `Error in dataframe$variable[odd_indexes, ] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rep()` does the trick:

```
dataframe$variable <- rep(c("Al", "Bt"), length.out=nrow(dataframe))
```

Comment: Thanks, very simple one-line solution!

Comment: @jogo - corrected the typo on length.out arg, had to add a comment to get over the 6 character minimum for an edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dataframe[odd_indexes, "variable"] <- "Al"

dataframe[even_indexes, "variable"] <- "Bt"
```

Comment: If I use `dataframe[odd_indexes,variable] <- "Al"` it returns this error: `Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, odd_indexes, variable, value = "Al") : 
  object 'variable' not found.` If I run `dataframe[odd_indexes,dataframe$variable] <- "Al"` it returns this error:
`Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, odd_indexes, dataframe$variable,  : 
  Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates detected).`

Comment: Sorry, there should be quotes around `variable`, I've edited my answer. Does that work?